# Using Nodejs to parse kubectl output "TypeError: item.spec.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, kubectl

Using nodejs trying to parse attribute value(number of replicas) by running child_process kubectl deployment json output
Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong??

** Error: var deploymentInfo = item.spec.map((c) => { return { replicas: c.replicas} }); ^ TypeError: item.spec.map is not a function **

`
{

```
"apiVersion": "v1",
"items": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
        "kind": "Deployment",
        "metadata": {
            "labels": {
                "env": "stage"
            },
            "name": "sl-deployment"
        },
        "spec": {
            "progressDeadlineSeconds": 2147483647,
            "replicas": 3,
            "revisionHistoryLimit": 3,
            "selector": {
                "matchLabels": {
                    "env": "nonprod",
                    "microservice": "svc-microservice",
                    "name": "sl-deployment"
                }
            },
            "strategy": {
                "rollingUpdate": {
                    "maxSurge": 1,
                    "maxUnavailable": 1
                },
                "type": "RollingUpdate"
            },
            "template": {
                "metadata": {
                    "labels": {
                        "env": "stage",
                        "microservice": "svc-microservice",
                        "name": "sl-deployment"
                    }
                },
                "spec": {
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "image": "myregistry/svc-microservice/sl-deployment:stage.4.30",
                            "name": "sl-deployment",
                            "resources": {
                                "limits": {
                                    "cpu": "6",
                                    "memory": "16Gi"
                                },
                                "requests": {
                                    "cpu": "2",
                                    "memory": "6Gi"
                                }
                            }
                
                        }
                    ]
                   
                }
            }
        }
    } ]`
```

Tried the code pasted below

```
exec(`kubectl get deployment -n svc-microservice -o json`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
          return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
          console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
          return;
        }
        var deployjson = JSON.parse(stdout);
        
        for (let item of deployjson.items) {
          
          var  deploymentInfo = item.spec.map((c) => { return { replicas: c.replicas} });
          for (let info of deploymentInfo) {
            metadata[name][info.name] = { deployment:info.replicas}
          }
        }
        })
```

**
**Error: var  deploymentInfo = item.spec.map((c) => { return { replicas: c.replicas} });
^
TypeError: item.spec.map is not a function**
**

Comment: Where does `datamaps` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `spec` property is an object, so you can't use the map function on it. The map function is only for arrays.

If you just want to grab the `replicas` property, you don't need to do anything special, just access the property on the spec object:

```js
item.spec.replicas
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dzylich. item.spec is an object

Below code worked for me

```
var deploymentInfo = deployjson.items.map((item) => {
               return { replicas: item.spec.replicas };
           });
```